# Google Webmaster Tools don't find sitemap.xml

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap, 302-redirect, github

I have a domain which I use in combination with [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) for my [homepage](http://nedderhoff.xyz). I have a `sitemap.xml`, which I submitted to Google Webmaster Tools. Unfortunately I get this error message:

`Redirection error, HTTP-Error: 302`

When I try to access http://nedderhoff.xyz/sitemap.xml it works perfectly fine. Any ideas?

**UPDATE Nov 26th**

Could it have anything to do with the CNAME entry beeing [without `http://`](https://help.github.com/articles/my-custom-domain-isn-t-working/), while Google expects things to be with `http://`? I wouldn't think it has, but I have no other explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just received an answer from the GitHub support:

> "GitHub Pages will sometimes respond with 302 Found redirects when you have A records set up for an apex domain. It's part of our DDoS mitigation system for GitHub Pages sites."

My problem is that my domain hoster doesn't support DNS CNAME Records, so I think that I have to deal with what I have.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Google hates pages in the sitemap that do any kind of redirect. So, try something from this few options that crossed my mind:

1. Don't let the page in the sitemap to redirect (the pages must give status code 200 - OK)
2. Change the pages in the sitemap with the landing pages.
3. Exclude redirect pages in sitemap.

Comment: I don't see where it gets a redirect. It says that I submitted 4 elements (which is correct), and 2 of them threw errors. One of them is the main page, and the other three are on the same level accessable through the navigation, so I don't get why it throws two errors. It should be all or nothing. Another question, what do you mean by "Change the pages in the sitemap with the landing pages"? What are the landing pages?

Comment: I just updated my question ...